# Angular2 - how to see model driven form data with console.log

Tags: javascript, angular

I have model driven form where i am trying to console.log 
this.userForm.email, but it gives me following error: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'FormGroup'. Can anyone help?

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
        <h2>User Data</h2>
            <form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                        <div class="form-group">
                             <label>Name</label>
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                               <label>Email</label>
                               <input type="text" #refName class="form-control" formControlName="email">
                               <b>{{refName.className}}</b>
                        </div>

                        <div formGroupName="address">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Street</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="street">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>City</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="city">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>PostalCode</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="postalcode">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
</div>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // see peab olema
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    userForm = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl('Brandon'),
        email: new FormControl(),
        address: new FormGroup({
        street: new FormControl(),
        city: new FormControl(),
        postalcode: new FormControl()
    })  
});
    onSubmit(){
        console.log(this.userForm.email);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `this.userForm.controls.email.value` instead.

Comment: or `this.userForm.get('email').value`